# output of calculation is undesired

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to get the basics down here of class definition and using a calculation

Here's the code

```
<?php

class calculator {
    var $number1 = 4;
    var $number2 = 5;

    function add ($a,$b){
        $c = $a + $b;
        print ("the sum of your numbers: $c");
        print ($c);
    }

}

$cal = new calculator;
$cal->add($number1,$number2);

?>
```

What appears in my browser is:

> The sum of your numbers: 0

Why not the 9?

Comment: Where are you defining `$getal1` and `$getal2`?

Comment: that was a translation mistake. getal means number in dutch. corrected now. Even with this correction the result is the same

Comment: Your arguments being sent are `$number1` and `$number2`. Are they numbers?

Comment: `print ($c);` is ambiguous. You have already printed `$c` in the previous line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the values of `$number1` and `$number2` that you are passing in? `$number1` and `$number2` are not the same as `$cal->number1` and `$cal->number2`.

You're defining two properties of an object, and passing two distinct, separate variables into the class's function. You basically have two pairs of numbers - one pair in the object, with values of 4 and 5, and one outside the function with no values (both 0) which you are then adding.

You could try this:

```
<?php
class calculator {
    private $number1 = 4;
    private $number2 = 5;

    function add ($a, $b){
        $c = $this->$a + $this->$b;
        print ("the sum of your numbers: $c");
        print ($c);
    }

}

$cal = new calculator;
$cal->add('number1', 'number2');
```

Or this:

```
<?php
class calculator {
    private $number1 = 4;
    private $number2 = 5;

    function add (){
        $c = $this->number1 + $this->number2;
        print ("the sum of your numbers: $c");
        print ($c);
    }

}

$cal = new calculator;
$cal->add();
```

Or this:

```
<?php
class calculator {
    function add ($a, $b){
        $c = $a + $b;
        print ("the sum of your numbers: $c");
        print ($c);
    }

}

$cal = new calculator;
$cal->add(4, 5);
```

Comment: god I'm really tired today. The values are 4 and 5 respectively. Even still I get this weird zero also with values assigned to the number1 and number2 variables.

Comment: greaet examples, very clarifying!

Comment: Now, that's a name I've not heard in a long time. A long time.

Answer (score 4):

You should either do

```
class calculator {
    //...
}
$number1 = 4;
$number2 = 5;
$cal = new calculator;
$cal->add($number1,$number2);
```

or

```
class calculator {
    var $number1 =4;
    var $number2 =5;
    //...
}
$cal = new calculator;
$cal->add($cal->number1,$cal->number2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `$number1` and `$number2` are being declared inside the scope of the class.

However when you call `$cal->add($number1, $number2)` you are now outside of that scope, so those values are undefined.